# Copy lines from one file to another, skipping multiple occurrences

Tags: bash, sed, output

I have a big file, results.txt, that I want to take certain lines out of and put them into another file. The data I want to take out is some variable, omega and alpha. However for results.txt, there are two  occurrences of  omega and alpha for each set of data in results.txt, and I only want the second set of data. I am not sure how to proceed. I know I should use SED but I don't know how since I have only found help regarding replacing lines use sed. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

## #

--- Sorry I was on mobile when I asked the question. Didn't know how to insert code. ---

So my file looks something like

```
Very big list of useless output
.
.
.
Results 1: 
Omega = 121
Distance = 18.7037218936
Alpha = -1.05958217593e-05
Result 5 = 18983
Result 6 = 1231.903
-------------------------
Results 1: 
Omega = 121
Distance = 18.7037218936
Alpha = -1.05958217593e-05
Result 5 = 18983
Result 6 = 1231.903
-------------------------
Second useless output for the next data set
.
.
.
```

The next data set begins after both sets of results. I have 600 data sets. I want to print Omega and Alpha from the second set of results from each dataset to some other file, preferably in two columns, which I don't know if it is possible.

I have tried using sed but the documentation I have found only talks about replacing words I searched for. Thanks for any help!

Comment: (1) Show a short section of sample input and the corresponding desired output.  If there are any special cases that are important to you, make sure that the sample input includes them.   (2) Show some code that you have tried.  Without any code,  people may think that you are treating SO as a code-writing service.

Comment: wrt `I know I should use SED` - no, you probably should not. sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. The standard UNIX tool for any other text processing is awk so chances are that is what you should use. We won't know until you provide a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output though.

Answer (score 0):

Made a test file for you:

```
$ cat > results.txt
foo
alpha 1
omega 1
foo
alpha 2
omega 2
foo
$ tac results.txt|grep -m 1 alpha; tac results.txt |grep -m 1 omega
alpha 2
omega 2
```